# How to add a Lazy Loading concept in sqlite?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

Example i have some 5000 records. I entered  into sqlite database.Passed some Query got some data showing into the UITableview.
 Problem is  when i am scrolling the table view its getting stuck.

Comment: It's nothing with sqlite, it's with some implementation issues. Where are you fetching the data from database ? Are you loading images to the tableViewCells ? If you need to load a small amount of data and later more data, you can achieve that by UIRefreshControl and LIMIT constraint

Answer (score 1):

If you are using core data, use fetchBatchSize on NSFetchRequest to load only those which are required. Use NSFetchedResultsController and fetchBatchSize to make it more efficient.